# Can we use the ES6 class syntax in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, aws-lambda

I would like to use the ES6 class syntax in AWS Lambda using Node 6.10, but I cannot get it to work:

```
class widget {
    constructor(event, context, callback) {
        callback(null, `all seems well!`);
    }
}

// module.exports.handler = widget; // "Process exited before completing request"
module.exports.handler = new widget(); // "callback is not a function"
```

Has anyone had success with using the class syntax? The class constructor does not get seen as a handler function apparently.

Comment: In your example, `callback` _isn't_ a function. Callback is the third argument and you aren't passing any at all. It isn't saying `widget` isn't a function. Your ES6 runs fine.

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters to `new widget()`, so of course it will fail.

Comment: Isn't the callback function provided by the AWS Lambda handler? Our calling THEIR handler is how we pass data back, or am I wrong? We get the event, context, and a callback FROM Lambda, right?

Comment: Did you intend to do `= widget;` to export the class constructor itself? Right now you're calling the constructor, and then exporting the class instance.

Comment: Actually I'm confused, why are you exporting the class at all? It looks like handlers are supposed to just be normal functions?

Comment: Re: "normal functions", which I am intending to be the constructor. The constructor IS the handler function, is the intent here.

Comment: The syntax is generally `exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {`

Comment: @adeneo, agreed, but that IS what I am giving it with the constructor, no?

Comment: Well, no, you're giving it an instance of `widget` ?

Comment: Just for background, I have several successful AWS Lambdas running in the normal way as @adeneo commented. I am just hacking around with how we might sugar things up a bit. I will return in a few hours and hack some more, and likely accept an answer. Again, just academic here with the newer ES6 capabilities

Comment: When you do `new widget()`, you've actually called the function with no arguments, hence `callback` is not a function, nor are any of the other arguments. `module.exports.handler` has to be a **reference** to a function that AWS can call with the correct arguments.

Comment: I think the fact that you included both `= widget` (in a comment) and `= new widget()` confused the question originally. We ended up focusing on why `new` didn't work instead of why the first one _also_ didn't work.

Comment: @adeneo - a **reference** to it, right.... that's what I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are not following the API that Lambda expects. As [the documentation says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html), it expects

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {};
```

which it would then call with

```
const handlers = require('your-module');
handlers();
```

The issue here is that ES6 classes need to be created with `new`. Since the Lambda API says it expects a function, it expects a callable function, not a constructable function. If you want to use a class, you'd need to export a function, e.g.

```
class widget {
  constructor(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, `all seems well!`);
  }
}

exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    new widget(event, context, callback);
};
```

Comment: And it is this important and not obvious detail that kills the effort to "ES6'ize" Lambda code: `"it expects a callable function, not a constructable function".` Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer to your question, yes, you can use ES6 classes with the Node 6 Lambda functions. But this code is not going to work.

The lambda handler is not going to call `new` on your class so your constructor won't fire if you just pass

```
module.exports.handler = widget;
```

It will call `widget(event, context, callback)`. If you call `new` before you pass it it off, then you don't yet have the callback reference from the handler. You are essentially creating a new object with no initialized values. You're calling `new widget()` but you're not passing anything it and then you are passing this new instance for the handler to call.

**There's no reason on earth (as far as I can tell) to do this, but you *could*:**

```
class widget extends Function {
    constructor(){
      super('...args', 'return this.__call__(...args)');
      return this.bind(this);    
    }

    __call__(event, context, callback) {
     callback(null, "Dude, this is wierd.")
   }
}
exports.handler = new widget()
```

Comment: Right, which as eluded, makes no sense to do. Bit it _IS_ creative! Without AWS Lambda calling `new` the effort to use this OOP sugar dies. **sad**